# Why do these custom functions print different values in Python?

Tags: python

Why does `bad_function`, but not `good_function`, print a different value every time I run it?

```
def bad_function(x = np.zeros(1)): # first function
    print(x)
    x[0] = np.random.randn(1)

bad_function() # 0
bad_function() # not zero


def good_function(x = None): # second function
    if x is None:
        x = np.zeros(1)
    print(x)
    x[0] = np.random.randn(1)

good_function() # zero
good_function() # zero
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've stumbled upon Python's most classic gotcha! Here's a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) about the subject. And an [informative writeup](http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm).

Comment: Where did you get this from? Seems unlikely that someone would demonstrate this "gotcha" but not say anything about it.

Comment: I edited to question to clarify that print/return problem. I have now also edited the title, which I originally missed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask yourself when `np.zeros(1)` is called in both cases. Alternatively, run this code:

```py
def printingFn():
    print("printingFn")
    return 42

def func1(x = printingFn()):
    print("func1")

def func2(x = None):
    if x is None: x = printingFn()
    print("func2")

func1()
func1()
func1()

print()

func2()
func2()
func2()
```

You'll see that only *one* call is made to `printingFn` in the `func1` sequence, because the default argument is calculated when the function is *defined,* not every time it is *called:*

```
printingFn
func1
func1
func1

printingFn
func2
printingFn
func2
printingFn
func2
```

That's also true of the `func2` sequence, in that the default argument of `None` is evaluated at function definition. However, the code that calls `printingFn`, since the argument is `None`, happens on each call.

What that means in your case is that the `good_function` variant of `x` is being created freshly every time the function is called. The `bad_function` variant is hanging around so maintains the changes made when you assign something to `x[0]`.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed and then this value is used in any future function calls.

Answer (score 1):

As @CrazyChucky and @irezwi mentioned, it's because of the default parameters. I highly recommend you go through CrazyChucky's link (and subsequent link)

If you're still not clear go to [a python visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display)

make sure you select python 3.6 with anaconda. you'll see in step 5 or 6 why this happens and you can keep this in mind for the future